# Can it be determined that the sum of the diagonal entries, of matrix A, equals the sum of eigenvalues of A

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question to ask down below, that I have been having some trouble with and would like some help and clarification on.

Suppose **A**  is an $n \times n$ matrix with (not necessarily distinct) eigenvalues $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \ldots, \lambda_{n}$. Can it be shown that:

(a) The sum of the main diagonal entries of **A**, called the *trace* of **A**, equals the sum of the eigenvalues of **A**.

(b) **A** $- ~ k$ **I** has the eigenvalues $\lambda_{1}-k, \lambda_{2}-k, \ldots, \lambda_{n}-k$ and the same eigenvectors as **A**.

Thank You very much.

Comment: For (a), see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28linear_algebra%29 . For (b), use the equation that defines eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 5):

For the first,

$$A = P^{-1} M P$$

Where M is a (upper triangular) matrix with eigenvalues of A as diagonal elements. This is what it means to say that  A is always similar to its Jordan form.

Use $Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$

$$Tr(A)= Tr( P^{-1} M P) = Tr(MPP^{-1})=Tr(M)=\sum_n\lambda_n$$

b) Let $B=A-kI$ with eigenvalues be $\chi_n$

Eigenvalues are determined by solutions of 
$$|B-\chi I|=0$$
or,
$$|A-(\chi+k)I|=0$$

but since you know $$|A-\lambda I|=0$$ you get $\chi_n = \lambda_n-k$

Let $Y$ be an eigenvector of $B$. So $BY=\chi Y$. Now plug stuff in for $B$ and $\chi$ and see what you'd get.

Comment: What does the Jordan form has to do with the upper triangular form? Also, you might want to elaborate on why an upper triangular has its eigenvalues on the diagonal.

Comment: @Christopher: given that you're asking something about the TRace of a matrix, you might have suspected that Tr stands for Trace :)

Comment: @Christopher "stuff" is the expressions got for B and $\chi$ earlier. @wild...life This is a question on trace which usually appears in textbooks after introducing diagonalizability, etc. So i assumed some familiarity with that.

Answer (score 4):

A more direct way of showing (a) (which doesn't involve the Jordan normal form) is to look at the second highest term in the characteristic polynomial
$$\det(\lambda I - A) = (\lambda - \lambda_1)(\lambda - \lambda_2) \dots (\lambda - \lambda_n).$$
When you expand the left-hand side using permutations and products of entries of $A$, you will get minus the sum of the diagonal entries of $A$ as the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$, and when you multiply out the right-hand side, you will get minus the sum of the eigenvalues as the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$.

Comment: @Christopher: If you find it hard to deal with the general $n \times n$ case right away, try it first for $n=2$ ($\det(\lambda-a,-b;-c,\lambda-d)=(\lambda-a)(\lambda-d)-(-b)(-c)=\dots$) and $n=3$ (similarly, using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus). Hopefully, you will then see a pattern that you can generalize to higher $n$.